# Изменение констант через указатели в C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, указатели, const

Доброго времени суток.

В Си с помощью указателя я могу изменить значение константы.

```
const int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
*p = 10;
printf("%d", a);
```

Вывод:`10`

В Си++ компилятором допускается следующий код:

```
const int a = 5;
int *p = (int *) &a;
*p = 10;
std::cout << *p << " " << a;
```

Вывод:`10 5`

Значение по адресу указателя p изменилось, в то время как сама a - нет? Как это работает?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос: https://youtu.be/P3Ip3WNxPVg?t=1233

Comment: Создатели языка вас обманули, `a` это не настоящая константа, поэтому вы ее и меняете. Почему вы все же наблюдаете вывод `10 5` в С++? Компилятор считает, что `a` константа, значение которой равно 5 и при печати `a` печатает *реальную константу 5*, а не значение памяти, адресуемое этим символьным именем. Почему компилятор Си ведет себя по другому? Не знаю. В принципе, в ответе вам правильно объяснили, что для некорректной программы (а с т.з. *языка* программа некорректная (изменение того, что компилятор не должен *позволять* изменить)) результат непредсказуем (imho это неправильно)

Answer (score 11):

Ни в С, ни в С++ никаким способами не разрешается изменять значение константного объекта. Любые попытки такого изменения приводят к *неопределенному поведению*. Именно неопределенное поведение вы и наблюдаете в обоих своих примерах.

Язык С

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
>   **6** If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, **the behavior is undefined**.

Язык С++

> **9.1.7.1 The cv-qualifiers**
>   **[4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4)** Except that any class member declared mutable can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime **results in undefined behavior**.

---

> В Си с помощью указателя я могу изменить значение константы.

Нет, конечно. Такая инициализация указателя не допускается ни в С, ни в С++

```
const int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

Неявного преобразования `const int *` к `int *` в этих языках нет. Такое преобразование можно сделать только явно. Но и явное преобразование не поможет вам "изменить константу".

> Как это работает?

Никак не работает. Неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Компилятор выдает warning, однако код компилируется, под словом "могу" подразумевается это

Comment: @Alexander Minaev: В С запрещена такая инициализация. А уж что выдает ваш компилятор - это вопросы вашего компилятора. В языках С и С++ нет понятия "warning", а есть понятие "стандартного диагностического сообщения". Ваш компилятор выдал вам диагностическое сообщение ? Да, выдал. Все остальное - ваши проблемы. Ваше "могу" не имеет никакого отношения к С.

Comment: Термин "компилируется" в С и С++ означает "проходит компиляцию без выдачи стандартных диагностических сообщений". Ваш код НЕ компилируется именно из-за этого "warning".

Comment: Некоторые компиляторы могут даже предупреждение не выдавать

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: А это уже будет грубый баг компилятора. Диагностическое сообщение на каждое нарушение ограничений (constraints) языка С - жесткое требование языка С. (Мне такие компиляторы не знакомы.)

Comment: @AnT, не согласен, что грубый баг,  просто в старых весиях компиляторов я замечал таеое, что    анализируя  int *p = (int *) &a;  он может допустить, что ьы ваша попытка инициализировать указатель, все таки прошла успешно.  Для этого он может  сам выделить  память под обьект или создать обьединение(мое предположение)

Comment: @AlexanderMinaev *"Компилятор выдает warning, однако код компилируется"* Какой именно компилятор?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Я говорю лишь о формальных требованиях спецификации языка С, которые однозначно требуют выдачи диагностического сообщения на каждый "constraint violation".

Comment: А зачем вобще С++ языком допускается снятие константности если это потенциально может привести к неопределённому поведению ? Чтобы предохранить программиста на все случаи жизни ? Или все таки местами это просто немного плохой дизайн языка С++. Мне, например ниразу ещё не приходилось применять  const_cast.

Comment: ampawd , явное снятие константы,  означает, что программист намеренно это делает, и язык дает возможность  сделать это, а вот просто взять и изменить значение константы, не разрешается, потому что вдруг вам нужно сохранять константность, а случайно взяли и присвоили где то значение(например, как в вашем примере)

Comment: @ampawd Одно из классических идиоматических применений `const_cast` - реализация константной и неконстантной версии метода класса, когда обе версии во всем остальном одинаковы. Вместо того, чтобы писать один и тот же код два раза, мы просто вызываем константную версию из неконстантной через каст.